# JSP not showing results

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oracle11g

I'm having issues with my Java servlet and application. I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand how to make these servlets work correctly and output in the browser. I have attached my code below, please point me in the direction to get this program to work correctly. I understand sample code vs being told what to do. I'm not looking for you to do my work, just need help visually. All help is greatly appreciated.

Servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class FormPost3 extends HttpServlet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Connection con = null;

public void Form3(){
    init();
    }

public void init(){
    try{
        Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:7070:XE", "student2", "pass");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (FNAME VARCHAR2(20),LNAME VARCHAR2(40), PHONE VARCHAR2(20))");
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<form action='" + request.getRequestURL() + "' method='post' >");
    out.println("First Name:");
    out.println("<input type='text' name='FNAME' />");
    out.println("<br>");

    out.println("Last Name:");
    out.println("<input type='text' name='LNAME' />");
    out.println("<br>");

    out.println("Phone:");
    out.println("<input type='text' name='PHONE' />");
    out.println("<input type='submit' value='Submit' />");
    out.println("</form>");

    out.println("</body></html>");
    out.close();
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
    try{
        if (con != null)
            init();
        String fname = request.getParameter("FNAME");
        String lname = request.getParameter("LNAME");
        String phone = request.getParameter("PHONE");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('" + fname + "', '" + lname + "', '" + phone + "')");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE");
        while (rset.next()){
            out.print("<pre>");
            out.print("First Name: " + rset.getString(1));
            out.print("</pre>");
            out.println();
            out.print("<pre>");
            out.print("Last Name: " + rset.getString(2));
            out.print("</pre>");
            out.println();
            out.print("<pre>");
            out.print("Phone: " + rset.getString(3));
            out.print("</pre><br>");
            out.println();
            out.println();
        }
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println(e.getMessage());
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <session-config>

        <session-timeout>

            30

        </session-timeout>

    </session-config>

   <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>FormPost3</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>FormPost3</servlet-class>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-name>FormPost3</servlet-name>

        <url-pattern>/FormPost3</url-pattern>

        </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

index.html

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <h3 align="center">Storing Employee Details</h3>

    <form action="/WFormPost3" method="post">

        <div align="center">

        Empno: <input type="text" size="20" name="empno"/>

        <br><br>

        Ename <input type="text" size="20" name="ename"/>

        <br><br>

        Salary <input type="text" size="20" name="sal"/>

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="insert" />

        <div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you get when you click the submit button ?

Comment: you are saying jsp is not showing results. where is that jsp code. make sure if you have any exception stack please add it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form action in index.html to
`<form action="WFormPost3" method="post">`

Make sure by debugging that there does not exists any exception in your `doPost` method of `WFormPost3.java` servlet.